# Sort array first string than numbers

Tags: ios, iphone, sorting

I want to sort array that contains string as well as number like A,B,1 A,2 A,V,Z,10 B I want to sort in this way A,B,V,Z,1 A,2 A,10 B. I have search on stack overflow but nothing found useful.

Please help...

Comment: So the `NSArray` contains instances of `NSString` and `NSNumber` objects?

Comment: yes, three thing it contains 1. Only string 2. Only Number 3. Mixture of string and number

Comment: please put your array content, which is useful to help you.

Comment: Have you try something?

Comment: "01 Track1",
"02 Track2",
"33 Track3",
"Track1",
"Track2",
"Track3",
"07
",

Comment: I have tried NSSortDescriptor, sortedArrayUsingComparator

Comment: After your edit it seems that the elements are always strings, some of them having a numerical prefix. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, and thats why I edited my question because some experts are giving me solution for string and numeric .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
NSArray *arr = @[@"A",@"B",@"Y",@"4 B",@"1 A",@"2 A",@"V",@"Z",@"10 B"];

NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [arr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    int aa = [a intValue];
    int bb = [b intValue];

    if (aa !=0 && bb != 0)
    {
        return (aa > bb);
    }
    if (aa == 0 && bb == 0)
    {
        return [a compare:b];
    }
    if (aa == 0) return -1;
    return 1;

}];
```

Output : (A,B,V,Y,Z,1 A,2 A,4 B,10 B)

Comment: integer comparison is broken: `return (aa > bb);` does not handle aa < bb case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a comparator block to sort the objects in your array depending on their type. Something like:

```
NSArray *array = @[ @"A", @"B", @1, @2, @"V", @"Z", @10 ];
NSArray *result = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {

    // If the objects are the same class, compare them normally
    if ([[obj1 class] isEqual:[obj2 class]]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)[obj1 compare:obj2];
    }

    // If the objects are different classes, numbers go after strings 
    if ([obj1 isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] && [obj2 isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if ([obj2 isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] && [obj1 isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }

return NSOrderedSame;
}];

NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
```

Comment: You need to prioritise string classes over number classes.

Comment: How do you mean? And for what reason?

Answer (score 0):

You could use sorting with comparator and check for instance of nsnumber or nsstring

From the Apple Docs:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {

    // check for instance here f.e. [obj1 isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]

    if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
NSArray * arr =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"01 Track1", @"02 Track2", @"33 Track3", @"Track1", @"Track2", @"Track3", @"07 ", nil];

NSArray *sortedTrack = [arr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2)
{
    return [obj1 compare:obj2];
}];

NSLog(@"%@",sortedTrack);
```

Output: (
    "01 Track1",
    "02 Track2",
    "07 ",
    "33 Track3",
    Track1,
    Track2,
    Track3
)

Comment: If change position of obj2 and obj1 in return then it will descending order. Output will be: (
    Track3,
    Track2,
    Track1,
    "33 Track3",
    "07 ",
    "02 Track2",
    "01 Track1"
But I think you want totally custom sort. Its hard to do it.

Comment: I want to do same as iTunes do while displaying Music list

Answer (score 0):

I've done test with this. It's working fine. Use this. But doubt about efficient.

```
 NSArray *sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {

        if ([obj1 isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [obj2 isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] )
        {
            return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        }
        else if ([obj1 isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] && [obj2 isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
        {
            if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
            }

            if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ([obj1 isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
            if ([obj2 isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
        }

        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSPredicate for filtering. Check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html)

```
NSArray *array = @[@"A", @1, @"Z", @"B", @10, @100, @"X"];

NSPredicate *numbersPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self isKindOfClass: %@", [NSNumber class]];
NSPredicate *stringsPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self isKindOfClass: %@", [NSString class]];

NSArray *numbersArray = [[array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:numbersPredicate] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
NSArray *stringsArray = [[array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:stringsPredicate] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

NSArray *sortedArray = [stringsArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:numbersArray];

NSLog(@"sortedArray = %@", sortedArray);
```

Result;

```
sortedNumbers = (A, B, X, Z, 1, 10, 100)
```

Comment: You've done two sorting. I think, It will cost more. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very short version taking advantage of Objective-C's dynamic binding and the fact that both `NSNumber` and `NSString` respond to `doubleValue` and `description`:

```
NSArray *array = @[ @"A", @"B", @1, @2, @"V", @"Z", @10 ];

NSArray *result = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSComparisonResult result = [@([obj1 doubleValue]) compare:@([obj2 doubleValue])];
    if (result != NSOrderedSame)
        return result;
    return [[obj1 description] compare:[obj2 description]];
}];
```

First we convert both `NSNumber` and `NSString` to double, box them and compare. Non-numerical strings will always return 0, so they compare equal.

So if the numerical comparison yields equal, we just do normal string compare, making sure both operands are strings.

(This puts negative numbers before non-numerical elements.)

Answer (score -2):

```
NSArray *value_array = @[ @"A", @"B", @"1", @"2", @"V",@"Z",@"10"];
NSArray *result_array = [value_array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                    @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"doubleValue"
                                                    ascending:YES]]];

NSLog(@"Sorted Array: %@", result_array);
```

Comment: Fix your code, or remove it. Not working solution will not help anybody.

Comment: [<__NSCFConstantString 0x271cb8> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key String_Number.' giving error

Comment: This code will **not** work in the situation where any strings in the array are not in order to start with. Try it with this input: `@[ @"B", @"A", @"1", @"2", @"V",@"Z",@"10"]` and you'll see that the strings don't get sorted.